# Are browser scripts mandated to run on a single thread?

Tags: javascript, html, multithreading, client-side

If an HTML page has several `script` elements, each with an `src` attribute, is it possible for a browser to run each of these scripts on a separate thread or will they be executed in some sequence?

I know that any event handlers that have been registered will run on a single-threaded event loop, but are browsers "permitted" to run the scripts themselves concurrently?

My sense is no, but where *would* such a rule even be defined?  Would it be part of the HTML specification?  Or is such behavior omitted, leaving browser writers free to concurrently load scripts if they wish?

Comment: the answer is yes. but, you can make more threads using webworkers.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html

Comment: @RayToal I don't know of a place where it is *explicitly prohibited*, but allowing concurrent execution of JavaScript "for the same environment" *breaks* the implicit program execution defined in ECMAScript, which does *not* account for concurrency. That is: while an implementation might *use* threads, it most certainly will *obtain an exclusive lock* prior to running JavaScript within the same "global context".

Comment: In addition to the rules listed in the link provided (and scattered throughout the rest of the specs for historical reasons), think for a second: if they were able to be executed out-of-order that would have the potential to radically break everything that already exists.

Comment: True (+1), but parsing all the rules surrounding "list of scripts that will execute in order as soon as possible" without actually seeing words to the effect of all scripts having to be executed in a single thread (sequentially) gave me pause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally execution is locked to one thread and scripts will be executed in the order they appear in the document. However, you can run scripts in background threads using Web Workers.

More info can be found in the W3C spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/workers/

Or on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Performance/Using_web_workers

Comment: I do like web workers but my question was motivated not by a desire to thread scripts, but whether I could _rely_ on two scripts referred to in an HTML page be run in sequence. :)

Comment: Ah, well then yes. You can rely on scripts running in exactly the order you encounter them on the page.